# Install referrer и Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

подскажите, как можно получить реферер в Unity3D . Я сделал плагин для android, в котором я создал класс, унаследованный от broadcastreceiver . И в методе onreceive я отправляю данные, но метод onreceive не вызывается. Приемник был добавлен в манифест плагина и Манифест Unity. в манифесте:

```xml
<receiver
    android:name="com.ahg.and.InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```java
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");

        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Loader", "GetReferrer",referrer);
    }
}
```

Подскажите в чём может быть причина,почему не срабатывает broadcasReceiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я напишу тем, кто интересуется этой проблемой: в OnReceive вам нужно вызвать методы не unity ( так как broadcastreceiver вызывается до запуска приложения), затем я сохраняю string referrer через sharedpreferences, а затем проверяю его в unity при запуске. Я надеюсь, что это поможет кому-то.